# Bokeh Graph not changing dynamically with click in column value in data table

Tags: python

I am trying to change a NetworkX graph by clicking a value in bokeh data table. I can see and visualize the required value in the layout box but the same value is not getting used to display/ change the NetworkX Graph.

I have tried using python call back, but its not working either.It says "Only JavaScript callbacks may be used with standalone output".

```
#from bokeh.io import vplot
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.graphs import 
from_networkx,NodesAndLinkedEdges,EdgesAndLinkedNodes
from bokeh.plotting import  figure
from bokeh.models import Plot,Range1d
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from datetime import date
from random import randint
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, 
TableColumn,Spinner
import bokeh.layouts as layouts
import bokeh.models.widgets as widgets
from bokeh.io import curdoc

source= ColumnDataSource(dict(CUSTOMER_NO = pr, priority = 
np.arange(1,len(pr)+1,1)))
columns = [TableColumn(field = "CUSTOMER_NO", title = "CUSTOMER_NO"), 
TableColumn(field = "priority", title = "PRIORITY")]
data_table = DataTable(source = source, columns = columns, width = 200, 
height = 280, editable = True, reorderable = False)

text_row =  TextInput(value = None, title = "Row index:", width = 420)
text_CUSTOMER_NO = TextInput(value = None, title = "CUSTOMER_NO:", width 
= 420)
text_priority = TextInput(value = None, title = "priority:", width = 420)


plot=figure(title='test',x_range=Range1d(-1.1,1.1), 
y_range=Range1d(-1.1,1.1),tools="",toolbar_location=None)
s = 
G.subgraph(nx.shortest_path(G.to_undirected(),text_CUSTOMER_NO.value))
pos=nx.planar_layout(s)
graph=from_networkx(s,pos)
plot.renderers.append(graph)

source_code = """
row = cb_obj.indices[0]
text_row.value = String(row);
text_CUSTOMER_NO.value = String(source.data['CUSTOMER_NO'][row])
text_priority.value = String(source.data['priority'][row]);"""

callback = CustomJS(args = dict(source = source, text_row = 
text_row,text_CUSTOMER_NO=text_CUSTOMER_NO,text_priority=text_priority), 
code = source_code)

source.selected.js_on_change('indices', callback)
layout = column(data_table, text_row,text_CUSTOMER_NO,text_priority, 
plot)
#show(layout)
bokeh.io.output_notebook()
bokeh.io.show(layout)
#bokeh.io.show(plot)
```

There is no error message given, the output shows a correct bokeh data table, the clicks on the customer no shows me correct values in layout boxs but the networkx shows a black triangle.

I was able to somehow achieve this using python callback.Can some one please help me to achieve the same using CustomJS.  The code is below.

```
from datetime import date
from random import randint
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn
import bokeh.layouts as layouts
import bokeh.models.widgets as widgets
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.io import vplot
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.graphs import 
from_networkx,NodesAndLinkedEdges,EdgesAndLinkedNodes
from bokeh.plotting import  figure
from bokeh.models import Plot,Range1d
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from datetime import date
from random import randint
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn
import bokeh.layouts as layouts
import bokeh.models.widgets as widgets
from bokeh.io import curdoc

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 3),(3,4),(5,6),(6,7),(8,9),(9,10)])
data = dict(
    CUSTOMER_NO=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    priority=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
)

d_source= ColumnDataSource(data)
columns = [TableColumn(field = "CUSTOMER_NO", title = "CUSTOMER_NO"), TableColumn(field = "priority", title = "PRIORITY")]
data_table = DataTable(source = source, columns = columns, width = 200, height = 280, editable = True, reorderable = False)

def table_select_callback(attr, old, new):
    # print 'here'
    # print new
    # selected_row = new['1d']['indices'][0]
    selected_row = new[0]
    s = G.subgraph(nx.shortest_path(G.to_undirected(), data['CUSTOMER_NO'][selected_row]))
    #download_count = data['downloads'][selected_row]
    #chart_data = np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=download_count)
    plot = figure(title='test',x_range=Range1d(-1.1,1.1),y_range=Range1d(-1.1,1.1), tools = ['reset', 'pan','wheel_zoom','save', 'lasso_select', ])
    #p = figure(title='bla')
    pos=nx.random_layout(s)
    graph=from_networkx(s,pos)
    plot.renderers.append(graph)
    #r = p.line(x=range(len(chart_data)), y=chart_data)
    root_layout.children[1] = plot

d_source.selected.on_change('indices', table_select_callback)
root_layout = layouts.Column(data_table, widgets.Div(text='Select customer number'))
curdoc().add_root(root_layout)
```